# How can I resolve cURL (56) SSL error -5961

Tags: curl, openssl

Am connecting to a client service using PHP/cURL and certificate/key provided. Below is the error I keep getting.

```
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961
```

Comment: Please add some more details to the question.

Comment: Hi @Divyessh, after installing the certificate from client, I try to curl to test connection but there is no handshake. Below is the curl error:> * SSL read: errno -5961
* Closing connection #0
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961